# MacOS Command Line for Track Pad Settings

Tags: command-line, ventura

In Ventura MacOS, I am trying to use a command line script for affecting the trackpad settings. Specifically, in this case, I am trying to turn on tap-to-click.  But I would also like to turn on double-tap to drag, and change the scroll direction. The command that I have found are the following, but they do not work in Ventura:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad Clicking -bool true
sudo defaults -currentHost write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1
sudo defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1
```

Can anyone here help with the correct commands for these tasks? Thanks!

For the purposes of the bounty, here is what I am looking for:

Command-line commands to do the following 3 things on MacOS Ventura:

1. Turn on tap-to-click on a Macbook trackpad
2. Reverse the scroll direction
3. Turn on double-tap-to-drag (for moving windows around).

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @zeeple - perhaps use `defaults read com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad` before turning on tap to click, then turn it on and see the difference after running again?

Comment: How does reading the value help? If this is run by a script, it would just be lost, right?

Comment: Hi @zeeple - if you aren't sure what values change - you do a read before making the change to work out the "pre-making change" values, and a read after to see what's changed - you then know the values to put in a script in a `defaults write` (know might be a bit strong - you have an idea of what might work).

Comment: i am having the same problem, can't seem to write to any settings under `com.apple.AppleMultiTouchTrackpad`

Comment: according to this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75356595/1678383, the problem might be that a running process simply overwrites any changes you make. So you'll have to kill that process before making the changes.

Answer (score 1):

One method of determining what preference keys are is to make the change in the GUI, and then sort `~/Library/Preferences` by Date Modified. You can then see which files have been modified by changing the options in System Settings. Then you can search those files for relevant terms.

Don't forget to include the hidden `.GlobalPreferences.plist`, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm setting up a new Mac with Ventura and have read of large inconsistencies in older system pref cmds, and unintended results in setting them via CLI (even when they do still exist). Due to Apple not publicly maintaining this info I tend to *manually* update most OS (mainly system & finder) prefs first, and leave the setup script for all other app installs and config.

Your best bet for figuring this out is to use git (or some other comparison tool) to compare system settings pre & post changing them manually... Something like:

1. `touch macos-defaults.txt`
2. `defaults read > macos-defaults.txt`
3. `git add .`
4. manually adjust the required setting
5. run `defaults read > macos-defaults.txt` again, then
6. run `git diff` or other to compare and see exactly what prefs changed

I've read recently that changing the trackpad or mouse scrolling behavior in Ventura changes the other (can't currently have different settings), so keep that in mind.

Good luck!